# Using a shared MySQL container

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose

Tl;Dr; Trying to get WordPress docker-compose container to talk to another docker-compose container.

On my Mac I have a WordPress & MySQL container which I have built and configured with a linked MySQL server.  In production I plan to use a Google Cloud MySQL storage instance, so plan on removing the MySQL container from the docker-compose file (unlinking it) and then separate shared container I can use from multiple docker containers.

The issue I'm having is that I cant connect the WordPress container to the separate MySQL container.  Would anyone be able to shed any light on how I might go about this?

I have tried unsuccessfully to create a network as well as tried creating a fixed IP that the local box has reference to via the /etc/hosts file (my preferred configuration as I can update the file according to ENV)

WP:

```
version: '2'

services:
  wordpress:
    container_name: spmfrontend
    hostname: spmfrontend
    domainname: spmfrontend.local
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80

    # creates an entry in /etc/hosts
    extra_hosts:
      - "ic-mysql.local:172.20.0.1"

    # Sets up the env, passwords etc
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: ic-mysql.local:9306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: root
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: spm

    # sets the working directory
    working_dir: /var/www/html

    # creates a link to the volume local to the file
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content

# Any networks the container should be associated with
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: ic-network
```

MySQL:

```
version: '2'

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: ic-mysql
    hostname: ic-mysql
    domainname: ic-mysql.local
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 9306:3306

    # Create a static IP for the container
    networks:
      ipv4_address: 172.20.0.1

    # Sets up the env, passwords etc
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root # TODO: Change this
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASS: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress

    # saves /var/lib/mysql to persistant volume
    volumes:
      - perstvol:/var/lib/mysql
      - backups:/backups

# creates a volume to persist data
volumes:
  perstvol:
  backups:

# Any networks the container should be associated with
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: ic-network
```

Comment: Can you share your docker-compose.yaml with us?

Comment: @YaronIdan Updated to include the docker file for the WP instance

Comment: This is not a dockerfile, it is a docker-compose.yaml. And why doesn't it include the mysql container?

Comment: @YaronIdan sorry, added

Comment: @YaronIdan It was updated to include it. Sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you probably want to do is create a shared Docker network for the two containers to use, and point them both to it. You can create a network using `docker network create <name>`. I will use `sharednet` as an example below, but you can use any name you like.

Once the network is there, you can point both containers to it. When you're using docker-compose, you would do this at the bottom of your YAML file. This would go at the top level of the file, i.e. all the way to the left, like `volumes:`.

```yaml
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: sharednet
```

To do the same thing on a normal container (outside compose), you can pass the `--network` argument.

```
docker run --network sharednet [ ... ]
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to do the trick. I have updated the files listed above for reference, but effectively WP is still unable to speak to the DB

Comment: @gazzwi86 You created the network with `docker create network ic-network`? It shows up in `docker network ls`?

Comment: managed to get it working by setting up an extra host and passing it the IP, as above. I just need to make sure the MySQL box retains a static IP now, but I'm not sure how to do so with an external network